# Путь к ANDROID_HOME содержит непонятный символ в начале строки

Tags: android, android-sdk, mobile-development, appium

Я пытаюсь запустить тест на Appium. Appium использует platform tools Android sdk. Папка с platform tools имеет path ‪C:\Users\admin\Desktop\android-sdk. Этот путь прописан в переменной среды ANDROID_PATH. Но при запуске теста я получаю сообщение о том, что данная папка не найдена, причем этот путь в информационном сообщении об ошибке содержит кракозябру в самом начале. Что это может быть такое, как от нее избавиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запустите командную строку и выполните`set ANDROID_PATH > out.txt`. Что запишется в файл out.txt?

Comment: Я прошу прощения, написал переменная среды ANDROID_PATH, хотя на самом деле, спрашивал о ANDROID_HOME. Для нее в файл записывается правильное значение ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\android-sdk, а ANDROID_PATH не определена. Сейчас попробовал перенести эту папку на диск E. Ошибка ушла, но вместо нее появилась новая: Unable to create a new remote session.  Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk'.